# Want to build Header component from Bootstrap template to React but my browser throwing below errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

Want to build Header component from Bootstrap template but my browser is throwing the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <NavLink> outside a <Router>
```

The above error occurred in the `<Router.Consumer>` component

I imported:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
```

in my Header.js
and converted my all `<a>` in `<NavLink to='/Shop' >Shop</NavLink>`

and my App.js is like this:

```
import Header from './components/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Home from './container/Home';
import Shop from './container/Shop';
import {Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom';


function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
          <Route path='/shop' exact component={Shop} />
        </Switch>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I think the error message is pretty self-explanatory, there is no `<Router>` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

In your App.js,
Add Router component

Like this

```
import Header from './components/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Home from './container/Home';
import Shop from './container/Shop';
import {Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';


function App() {
  return (
    <>
        <Router>
           <Header />
            <Switch>
              <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
              <Route path='/shop' exact component={Shop} />
            </Switch>
           <Footer />
        </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).